# Roles in AspNetRoles in RoleManager AspNet.Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, roles

Here the Role table having three roles. where the last two record (Doctor and FrontDesk) is manually inserted in database.

But when i get roles list form using owin context rolemanger. i can't get records which i manually added.

[image]

> swagger output:[ { "id": "b45b6ccb-e849-41d2-b190-fd45da8e2c4e",
>   "name": "Admin", } ]

Comment: swagger output:[
  {
    "id": "b45b6ccb-e849-41d2-b190-fd45da8e2c4e",
    "name": "Admin",   
  }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the discriminator of Doctor and FrontDesk to `ApplicationRole`.